# How to fix 'illegal start of expression' error for the second method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish an assignment with nested if/else structures and while loops. However, somehow my second method is causing errors. Let me know if you can help me, as this is my first question on SO.

I've tried closing the first method with brackets, but this only caused more errors. I don't know where else to go from here, I've looked all over google for help.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PA1 {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while((senitel == 'y')||(senitel == 'Y')); {
      menu();
      System.out.printf("Enter your choice: ");
      choice = in.nextInt();
      redo = in.nextLine();
      while(choose ==true) {
        if(choice==1) {
          choice = false;
          computer = "HP Envy 13\n";
          System.out.printf("Enter the quantity for the %s", computer);
          quantity = in.nextInt();
          subtotal = subtotal +799.99; }
        else if (choice==2) {
          choose = false;
          computer = "Asus ZenBook 13 UX333FA\n";
          System.out.printf("Enter qunatity for the %s", computer);
          quantity = in.nextInt();
          subtotal = subtotal + 849.99; }
        else {
          choose = false;
          System.out.println("In Else");
          System.out.printf("Invalid choice! Try again.\n");
          System.out.printf("Enter 'Y' to add a laptop to your purchase or 'N' to exit: ");
          redo = in.nextLine(); }

        if((choice>=1)&&(choice<=5)) {
          choice = true;}
        else {
          choice = false;
          menu();
          choice = in.nextInt();}}

      redo = in.nextLine();
      System.out.printf("Enter 'Y' to add a laptop to your purchase or 'N' to exit: ");
      reply = in.nextLine();
      senitel = reply.charAt(0);}

    System.out.println("Out");
    choice = 3;

    if(choice>0) {
      if(choice<6) {
        System.out.printf("LAPTOP ORDER SUMMARY\n\n");
        System.out.printf("%s",orderSummary);
        System.out.printf("Date:\n");
        System.out.printf("Time:\n\n");
        tax = subtotal + .0825;
        total = subtotal + tax;
        int trigger =1;

     String laptop = "";
     int lineItem = 0;
     if(trigger == 1) {
       orderSummary += String.format("%n%,-9d %-30s %8s $%,17.2f",
                         qty, laptop, " ", lineItem);
       trigger = 0; }
     else {
       orderSummary += String.format("%n%,-9d %-30s %9s %,17.2f",
                         qty, laptop, " ", lineItem);}


     orderSummary += String.format("%n%n%34s Subtotal %6s %,17.2f"
                                     + "%n%31s Tax @ 8.25%% %6s %,17.2f"                    
                                     + "%n%n%37s TOTAL %5s $%,17.2f%n",
                                     " ", " ", subtotal,
                                     " ", " ", tax,
                                     " ", " ", total);
     System.out.printf("%s", orderSummary); }}



public static void menu(){
Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.printf("%nTOP LAPTOPS OF %tY"
                    + "%n%n1.  %-23s %7s $%,9.2f"
                    + "%n2.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                    + "%n3.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                    + "%n4.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                    + "%n5.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                    + "%n%nEnter your choice:  ",
                    dateTime,
                    "HP Envy 13", " ", 799.99,
                    "Asus ZenBook 13 UX333FA", " ", 849.99,
                    "Dell XPS 13", " ", 989.99,
                    "Alienware Area 51-m", " ", 1999.99,
                  "Razer Blade Stealth", " ", 1299.00); }



public static void trig() {
  int trigger = 1;
  String orderSummary = "";
  int quantity = 0;
  String laptop = "";
  int lineItem = 0;
  if(trigger==1) {
    orderSummary += String.format("%n%, -9d %-30s %8%s $%, 17.2f",
                                  quantity, laptop, " ", lineItem);
    trigger =0; }
  else {
    orderSummary += String.format("%n%, -9d %-30s %9s %, 17.2f",
                                  quantity, laptop, lineItem); }

  orderSummary += String.format("%n%n%34s Subtotal %6s %,17.2f"
                                     + "%n%31s Tax @ 8.25%% %6s %,17.2f"                    
                                     + "%n%n%37s TOTAL %5s $%,17.2f%n");

  System.out.printf("%s", orderSummary); }}
```

Comment: Use an IDE to auto indent your braces, they're probably off.

Comment: You're missing a brace at the end of your first function

Comment: Also read: [Whats wrong with this while loop?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2610679)

Answer (score 0):

Well here's one problem right away:

```
while( (senitel == 'y') || (senitel == 'Y') );
{
```

See that semi-colon at the end?  Probably not what you want.

Auto-indent your code with an IDE.  Then go through all of it and fix the syntax errors.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten curly brackets.

Here is your fixed example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PA1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while ((senitel == 'y') || (senitel == 'Y')) ;
        {
            menu();
            System.out.printf("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = in.nextInt();
            redo = in.nextLine();
            while (choose == true) {
                if (choice == 1) {
                    choice = false;
                    computer = "HP Envy 13\n";
                    System.out.printf("Enter the quantity for the %s", computer);
                    quantity = in.nextInt();
                    subtotal = subtotal + 799.99;
                }
                else if (choice == 2) {
                    choose = false;
                    computer = "Asus ZenBook 13 UX333FA\n";
                    System.out.printf("Enter qunatity for the %s", computer);
                    quantity = in.nextInt();
                    subtotal = subtotal + 849.99;
                }
                else {
                    choose = false;
                    System.out.println("In Else");
                    System.out.printf("Invalid choice! Try again.\n");
                    System.out
                            .printf("Enter 'Y' to add a laptop to your purchase or 'N' to exit: ");
                    redo = in.nextLine();
                }

                if ((choice >= 1) && (choice <= 5)) {
                    choice = true;
                }
                else {
                    choice = false;
                    menu();
                    choice = in.nextInt();
                }
            }

            redo = in.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("Enter 'Y' to add a laptop to your purchase or 'N' to exit: ");
            reply = in.nextLine();
            senitel = reply.charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Out");
        choice = 3;

        if (choice > 0) {
            if (choice < 6) {
                System.out.printf("LAPTOP ORDER SUMMARY\n\n");
                System.out.printf("%s", orderSummary);
                System.out.printf("Date:\n");
                System.out.printf("Time:\n\n");
                tax = subtotal + .0825;
                total = subtotal + tax;
                int trigger = 1;

                String laptop = "";
                int lineItem = 0;
                if (trigger == 1) {
                    orderSummary += String.format("%n%,-9d %-30s %8s $%,17.2f",
                                                  qty, laptop, " ", lineItem);
                    trigger = 0;
                }
                else {
                    orderSummary += String.format("%n%,-9d %-30s %9s %,17.2f",
                                                  qty, laptop, " ", lineItem);
                }


                orderSummary += String.format("%n%n%34s Subtotal %6s %,17.2f"
                                                      + "%n%31s Tax @ 8.25%% %6s %,17.2f"
                                                      + "%n%n%37s TOTAL %5s $%,17.2f%n",
                                              " ", " ", subtotal,
                                              " ", " ", tax,
                                              " ", " ", total);
                System.out.printf("%s", orderSummary);
            }
        }


    }

    public static void menu() {
        Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.printf("%nTOP LAPTOPS OF %tY"
                                  + "%n%n1.  %-23s %7s $%,9.2f"
                                  + "%n2.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                                  + "%n3.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                                  + "%n4.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                                  + "%n5.  %-23s %8s %,9.2f"
                                  + "%n%nEnter your choice:  ",
                          dateTime,
                          "HP Envy 13", " ", 799.99,
                          "Asus ZenBook 13 UX333FA", " ", 849.99,
                          "Dell XPS 13", " ", 989.99,
                          "Alienware Area 51-m", " ", 1999.99,
                          "Razer Blade Stealth", " ", 1299.00);
    }


    public static void trig() {
        int trigger = 1;
        String orderSummary = "";
        int quantity = 0;
        String laptop = "";
        int lineItem = 0;
        if (trigger == 1) {
            orderSummary += String.format("%n%, -9d %-30s %8%s $%, 17.2f",
                                          quantity, laptop, " ", lineItem);
            trigger = 0;
        }
        else {
            orderSummary += String.format("%n%, -9d %-30s %9s %, 17.2f",
                                          quantity, laptop, lineItem);
        }

        orderSummary += String.format("%n%n%34s Subtotal %6s %,17.2f"
                                              + "%n%31s Tax @ 8.25%% %6s %,17.2f"
                                              + "%n%n%37s TOTAL %5s $%,17.2f%n");

        System.out.printf("%s", orderSummary);
    }
}
```

Use some IDE that points to errors.